# How do i gzip multiple files using python

Tags: python

Pavan here,

I've been trying to gzip multiple files using python scripting.

I've files named as like 1.txt, 2.txt --- 99.txt.

I've to convert all the .txt to .gz files.

I know to gzip one file at once as below

```
import gzip

f_in = open('path')

f_out = gzip.open('path', 'wb')

f_out.writelines(f_in)

f_out.close()

f_in.close()
```

Any suggestions about this please

Thank you

Comment: I don't see any code where you try to gzip multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you list the files in a directory and compress each one. Here is code that builds off one of the [gzip examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage)

```
import pathlib
import gzip
import shutil

target_dir = pathlib.Path('/home/joe/')
for child in target_dir.iterdir():
    # Skip directories
    if child.is_dir():
        continue
    # You could also check for just .txt files here if desired
    with child.open('rb') as f_in:
        with gzip.open(str(child.with_suffix(".txt.gz")), 'wb') as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

With a directory structure like

```
/home/joe/
|-- subdir
|-- a.txt
|-- b.txt
|-- c.txt
```

This snippet will generate

```
/home/joe
|-- subdir
|-- a.txt
|-- a.txt.gz
|-- b.txt
|-- b.txt.gz
|-- c.txt
|-- c.txt.gz
```

If you want to remove the original files you could add `child.unlink()` after the `with` context.

Answer (score 0):

*I've to convert all the .txt to .gz files.*

Take look at [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) built-in module, especially [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) function. Consider following example

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    print(filename)
```

It does print all names of .txt files inside current working directory. You need to add calculating new name to it (e.g. `newname = filename + ".gz"`) and mate it with your code for gzip-ing and it will then apply that action to every .txt file.